# Regular expression for all abbreviated keyword variations

Tags: regex

I need to search for a keyword, such as "abcdef", which can also be in an abbreviated version with a dot at the end. All valid variants are:

```
abcdef
abcde.
abcd.
abc.
ab.
a.
```

I have a regular expression for this, which is clear:

```
abcdef|abcde\.|abcd\.|abc\.|ab\.|a\.
```

Another regular expression where the keyword characters are not repeated:

```
a(b(c(d(e(f|\.)|\.)|\.)|\.)|\.)
```

I'm looking for a more compact expression where not even a dot will be repeated.
I use .NET syntax.

Comment: Maybe `a(b(c(d(ef?)?)?)?)?(?:(?<!f)\.)?`? Or `a(b(c(d(ef?)?)?)?)?(?:(?<!abcdef)\.)?`

Comment: Well, if you has a PCRE regex flavor, you could use `a(b(c(d(e(f(*ACCEPT))?)?)?)?)?\.?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OdBlwd/1). .NET regex does not support PCRE verbs. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional construct:

```
a(b(c(d(e(?<f>f)?)?)?)?)?(?(f)|\.?)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=a%28b%28c%28d%28e%28%3f%3cf%3ef%29%3f%29%3f%29%3f%29%3f%29%3f%28%3f%28f%29%7c%5c.%3f%29&i=abcdef.%0d%0aabcdef%0d%0aabcde.%0d%0aabcd.%0d%0aabc.%0d%0aab.%0d%0aa.). Here, `(?<f>f)?` is an optional named group matching `f` one or zero times. If the group matches, the `f` group is not empty, and `(?(f)|\.?)` matches an empty string then. If it is empty, `\.?` matches an optional `.`.

In PCRE falvor, could use

```
a(b(c(d(e(f(*ACCEPT))?)?)?)?)?\.?
```

where `(*ACCEPT)` verb inside an optional group would stop analyzing the current regex and return the value matched so far (so the last `\.?` would not be tried if `f` is found). See [this regex flavor](https://regex101.com/r/OdBlwd/1).

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to verify that there is no simple expression for shortening a string.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant:
`a(bcdef|(bcde|bcd|bc|b|)\.)`

With shorting 2 letters (a bit shorter):
`a(bcdef|(b(cde|cd|c|)|)\.)`
With shorting 3 letters (the same length):
`a(bcdef|(b(c(de|d|)|)|)\.)`

With shorting 4 letters the shortest - 25 symbols:
`a(bcdef|(b(c(de?|)|)|)\.)`